# OpenLayers3 - How to redraw or refresh a WMS Layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm working on a kind-of live map.

From times to times, is necessary to refresh the layer to get the refreshed content (as the page does not reload).

I tried to remove/add the layer again with `setInterval` but the layer is not added again.

```
setInterval(function() {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
    map.addLayer(layer);
}, 10000);
```

There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that setting a timeout before the `addLayer` do the job. It just *smells* a little bit.

```
setInterval(function() {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
    setTimeout(function() {
        map.addLayer(layer);
    }, 100);
}, 10000);
```